# jQuery vTicker stop autoplay

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery vTicker to scroll my news items.

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tx_newsitems').vTicker({
    speed: 500,
    pause: 3000,
    animation: 'none',
    mousePause: true,
    height: 0,
    direction: 'up',
  });
});
```

Actual problem is i need to stop autoplay in this plugin. Is it possible?
Is any code like this `autoplay:false,` ?

Comment: According to the github readme, you can use isPaused: https://github.com/richhollis/vticker does that help?

Comment: Apparently there is an option for pausing it the samples here pause on mouse hover on a separate button. YOu can check it out at https://github.com/richhollis/vticker

Answer (score 0):

You need add after initialization vTicker-function code:

```
$("#id of stop/start - button").toggle(function(){ 
  $('.tx_newsitems').vTicker('pause', true);
},function(){ 
  $('.tx_newsitems').vTicker('pause', false);
});
```

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tx_newsitems').vTicker({
    speed: 500,
    pause: 3000,
    animation: 'none',
    mousePause: true,
    height: 0,
    direction: 'up',
  });

  $("#stop_start_button").toggle(function(){ 
     $('.tx_newsitems').vTicker('pause', true);
  },function(){ 
     $('.tx_newsitems').vTicker('pause', false);
  });
});
```